# How to start second QDialog window on side of MainWindow?

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qdialog, qt5.4

I have a application in Qt, and a MainWindow. Now, I also added a helping QDialog which can be hooked up. This QDialog does not influence the programmflow, it just displays information.

But, it always starts on top of the MainWindow :/

SO I would like to start it on the side of the main window, so that it does not hinder the view to the main window?? How?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , You should try this,

1. Use the overload of the QWidget::setParent() function to change the ownership of a QDialog widget, using set as NULL(but It will not share the parent's taskbar entry).
2. QDialog::show() returns control to the caller immediately, So it will not interfere in mainwindow flow.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, your application is in the full screen mode. Where then the **QDialog** should appear? It will be shown on the top and you won't be satisfied again.

If it doesn't influence the flow of the app then you are using it to communicate some sort of message. Can you use different ways? For instance, **QStatusBar**?

If not, why not to split the mainWindow with **QSplitter** or similar classes and provide an area where you can post all the info messages?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you want modaless dialog. In main window, use a slot to create the dialog.

```
void MainWindow::show_dialog()
{
    if ( pDialog== NULL )
         pDialog= new XYZ_Dialog(this);

    QPoint p = pos();
    QSize  s = frameSize();
    pDialog->setGeometry(p.x()+s.width(), p.y(), s.width()*1/2, s.height());

    pDialog->show();
}
```

What I try to say is if the position of the new dialog bothers you, you set the position and size of it, before showing it.